# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a Mern project, as soon as i'm testing the POST(adding movie to a cart ), i got this error, don't know where it come from this error, tried everything.

Here is my **Client.js**

```
"use strict"


import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom' ;
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Router,Route,IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';


import {applyMiddleware, createStore,compose} from 'redux';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";


import reducers from './reducers/index';

import {addToCart} from './actions/cartActions';

const middleware =applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger());
const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);
```

My function on **moviesActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export function postMovies(movie){
    return function (dispatch){
        axios.post("/movies",movie)
            .then(function(response){
                dispatch({type:"POST_MOVIE", payload:response.data})
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                dipsatch({type:"POST_MOVIE_REJECTED", payload:"there was an error while posting a new movie"})
            })

    }
}
```

Comment: You have typed "dipsatch" in your catch function. Apart from that we don't have enough info to understand your problem. Your store creation looks fine, why don't you show your Provider and the part where you dispatch this postMovies actions?

Comment: What should i add to make it clear ?

Comment: case "POST_MOVIE":

  return {...state,movies:[...state.movies, ...action.payload]};